# Getting error while applying sum function(group function is not allowed here)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to apply a sum function on a table column but i am getting error that

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
00934. 00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 5
```

Here is the query

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",  
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "BRANCH",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "Officer Name",
   LOSA_CUST.full_name AS "Borrower",
   LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type AS "Facility Type",
   losa_facilities.amt_appr AS "Limit"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
...
INNER JOIN
    losa_facilities LOSA_FACILITIES
ON
    LOSA_APP.app_ref_no = LOSA_FACILITIES.app_ref_no
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A' 
and 
    .....
and 
    sum(losa_facilities.amt_appr)
```

Line 46 is `sum(losa_facilities.amt_appr)` i also tried `sum(losa_facilities.amt_appr) group by losa_facilities.amt_appr` but it didn't work.

Why it is saying that `group function is not allowed here ?`. What i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

***EDIT:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------***

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",  
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "BRANCH",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "Officer Name",
   LOSA_CUST.full_name AS "Borrower",
   LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type AS "Facility Type",
   LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr AS "Limit"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
    losa_app_z LOSA_APP_Z  
ON
    losa_app.app_ref_no = losa_app_z.app_ref_no 
INNER JOIN
    code_branch CODE_BRANCH
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_branch = CODE_BRANCH.branch_id
INNER JOIN
    code_staff CODE_STAFF
ON
    LOSA_APP.attend_staff = CODE_STAFF.staff_id
INNER JOIN
    losa_cust LOSA_CUST
ON
    LOSA_APP.app_ref_no = LOSA_CUST.app_ref_no
INNER JOIN
    losa_facilities LOSA_FACILITIES
ON
    LOSA_APP.app_ref_no = LOSA_FACILITIES.app_ref_no
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A' 
and 
    trunc(sysdate) between (nvl(LOSA_APP_Z.li_dt, LOSA_APP_Z.li_collect_dt)) AND ((trunc(sysdate))) -- falling under the reporting period
and
    (trunc(sysdate) - nvl(losa_app_z.li_dt,losa_app_z.li_collect_dt)) > 90  -- select application cases at any step after entering Documentation flows.
and 
    losa_app.product_type = :productType -- Select records based on input parameter value passed in. 
and
    code_branch.branch_code1 -- Attending IHP Branch passed in from input parameter
    like
    case :inputChannel 
        when 'ABB'  Then '%0232%'
        when 'AiBB' Then '%0347%' 
    end
and
    LOSA_CUST.app_joint_t = 'P' -- Name of PS No. staff name
and 
    GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name, CODE_STAFF.staff_name, LOSA_CUST.full_name, LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type) 
    HAVING sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) > 0
```

Error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 5
```

Line 46 is `GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name,...`

I also tried this

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",  
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "BRANCH",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "Officer Name",
   LOSA_CUST.full_name AS "Borrower",
   LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type AS "Facility Type",
   sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) AS "Limit"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
INNER JOIN
....
```

Just use sum in the select clause, but in this case i get error that

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use aggregate functions (like SUM/AVERAGE etc.,) you need to group the results using the `GROUP BY` clause. To filter results based on the aggregation on a column, you should perform a `GROUP BY` on the selected columns, and then use the `HAVING` clause to specify the filter

```
select LOSA_APP.app_ref_no AS "App.Ref.No.",  
   CODE_BRANCH.branch_name AS "BRANCH",
   CODE_STAFF.staff_name AS "Officer Name",
   LOSA_CUST.full_name AS "Borrower",
   LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type AS "Facility Type",
   losa_facilities.amt_appr AS "Limit"
from losa_app LOSA_APP
...
INNER JOIN
    losa_facilities LOSA_FACILITIES
ON
    LOSA_APP.app_ref_no = LOSA_FACILITIES.app_ref_no
where 
    LOSA_APP.app_status='A' 
and 
    .....
GROUP BY <all the columns in the  SELECT clause above, except those on which aggregate functions are applied>
HAVING sum(losa_facilities.amt_appr) <relational operator and value>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but now i am getting error that `ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 5` Here what i did now `and 
    GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name, CODE_STAFF.staff_name, LOSA_CUST.full_name, LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type) 
    HAVING sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr)`

Comment: `HAVING sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr)` is not a valid expression. If you just want to select the sum, then include `sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr)` in the select list. But if you want to filter results based on sum, then use the `HAVING` clause as `HAVING sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) > 100`, something like this.

Comment: i tried this now but i am getting the same error that `ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 46 Column: 5`. Here what i did now `and 
    GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name, CODE_STAFF.staff_name, LOSA_CUST.full_name, LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type) 
    HAVING sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) > 0`. Now there is condition. What is going wrong now ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the latest query that you are trying to run, as is?

Comment: Please add the entire query, your edit doesn't have the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: I added the full query in my edit.... scroll down the query in the edit section...

Comment: I posted two queries one is full in which Group By clause is present and the second is just a snippet of the select clause in which i use sum() in the select clause. Please scroll down the first query...Hope you got it now ...

Comment: Remove the "AND" before GROUP BY. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: hhmm thanks :). But i want to ask another thing, you mentioned that `<all the columns in the  SELECT clause above, except those on which aggregate functions are applied>`. If i omit the `LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr` column in the `GROUP BY clause`, then i also get error that `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
Error at Line: 6 Column: 8`, but if i include the column, then query runs, mean if i write like `GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name, CODE_STAFF.staff_name, LOSA_CUST.full_name,  LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type)` omit column, cont...

Comment: cont..  i get error but if include the column like `GROUP BY (LOSA_APP.app_ref_no, CODE_BRANCH.branch_name, CODE_STAFF.staff_name, LOSA_CUST.full_name,  LOSA_FACILITIES.fac_type, LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr)`, column included then query runs. Why you said that `except those on which aggregate functions are applied` ?

Comment: Also you said that `If you just want to select the sum, then include sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) in the select list` but in the select clause it didn't work `...sum(LOSA_FACILITIES.amt_appr) AS "Limit"
from losa_app LOSA_APP` ?

Comment: search for GROUP BY on this page at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/select.html and you would see what i was trying to say in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SUM() and other group-by functions must appear in a HAVING clause, not in a WHERE clause.